# Finding the output using SQL query

Tags: sql-server

If you want to be sure you get all the dates in your range, if the range values are `'2015-07-01' and '2015-07-17'` but we get the output

```
Mr.Akbar Thekkan Thiruthinmel Mohammed Kutty    PATHOLOGY   12/12/2021  24/06/2016  24/06/2016  17/07/2015  17/07/2015  07/06/2016
Mr.Arif Gullu Muhammed                          PATHOLOGY   13/06/2022  18/10/2016  18/10/2016  16/07/2015  16/07/2015  26/09/2016
Mr.Rafeek Kuzhikkal                             PATHOLOGY   18/09/2021  12/08/2015  12/08/2015  17/07/2015  17/07/2015  30/06/2015
Ms.Marie Ann Taguran Calog                      PATHOLOGY   09/05/2017  13/12/2016  13/12/2016  16/07/2015  16/07/2015  22/11/2016
Ms.Shameema Saud Rafeeq                         PATHOLOGY   16/07/2015  16/07/2015  16/07/2015  16/07/2015  16/07/2015  16/07/2015
Ms.Thresiamma Royi                              NURSE       15/10/2017  09/04/2016  04/04/2016  16/07/2015  16/07/2015  16/07/2015
Ms.Zahara Beegum                                PATHOLOGY   16/07/2015  16/07/2015  16/07/2015  16/07/2015  16/07/2015  16/07/2015
```

The query:

```
select * 
from dbo.tblEmpMaster E 
left outer join tblDepartment D on e.emp_Deptid = D.Id
where 
    E.emp_PassExpDate between '2015-07-01' and '2015-07-17'
    or (E.emp_VisaExpDate between '2015-07-01' and '2015-07-17') 
    or (E.emp_EmiratesExp between '2015-07-01' and '2015-07-17')
    or (E.emp_MOHExpDate between '2015-07-01' and '2015-07-17')
    or (E.emp_MalInsExp between '2015-07-01' and '2015-07-17' )
    or (E.emp_LbrCardDate between '2015-07-01' and '2015-07-17')
```

Comment: Provide your query what you have tried.

Comment: select  *
  from dbo.tblEmpMaster E 
 left outer join tblDepartment D on e.emp_Deptid =D.Id   where E.emp_PassExpDate between '2015-07-01' and '2015-07-17' 
 or (E.emp_VisaExpDate between '2015-07-01' and '2015-07-17') or  
  (E.emp_EmiratesExp between '2015-07-01' and '2015-07-17') or
( E.emp_MOHExpDate between '2015-07-01' and '2015-07-17') or
(E.emp_MalInsExp between '2015-07-01' and '2015-07-17' )or
  (E.emp_LbrCardDate between '2015-07-01' and '2015-07-17')

Comment: What appears to be the problem? Based on your query, as long as at least one of the date columns provided in the where-clauses, then that row will be returned. Are you expecting more results?

Comment: help me write the query

Comment: Could you try putting opening brace right after where and closing brace at the very end, just to rule out precedence as an issue? and while you are at it, braces around the first between clause too.

Comment: not working,can you help me combine the ouput of two queries to single one

Comment: Can you try this? replace 'where' with 'AND'. Basically putting all the conditions under the 'ON' clause. Still retain the braces covering all the 'between' clauses.

Answer (score 0):

Use `AND` instead of `OR` if you want to retrieve all dates on exact range. Try to use like:

```
select * 
from dbo.tblEmpMaster E 
left outer join tblDepartment D on e.emp_Deptid = D.Id
where 
       (E.emp_PassExpDate between '2015-07-01' and '2015-07-17')
    and(E.emp_VisaExpDate between '2015-07-01' and '2015-07-17') 
    and(E.emp_EmiratesExp between '2015-07-01' and '2015-07-17')
    and(E.emp_MOHExpDate between '2015-07-01' and '2015-07-17')
    and(E.emp_MalInsExp between '2015-07-01' and '2015-07-17' )
    and(E.emp_LbrCardDate between '2015-07-01' and '2015-07-17')
```

Sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE #t1
(
    date1 date,
    date2 date,
    date3 date
)
INSERT INTO #t1 VALUES
('2015-02-03', '2015-02-04', '2015-02-05'),
('2015-01-03', '2015-02-05', '2015-02-06'),
('2015-02-07', '2015-02-08', '2015-02-09')

SELECT * FROM #t1
WHERE (date1 between '2015-02-01' and '2015-02-27')
      and (date2 between '2015-02-01' and '2015-02-27')
      and (date3 between '2015-02-01' and '2015-02-27')

DROP TABLE #t1
```

---

You can try demo  at 
**<kbd>[SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/cda56/1)</kbd>**